# Pagination table show TR by select option

Tags: jquery, html, pagination

For basic pagination I use this script.

```
$('table.paginated').each(function() {
var currentPage = 0;
var numPerPage = 5;
var $table = $(this);
$table.bind('repaginate', function() {
    $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
});
$table.trigger('repaginate');
var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
    $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
        newPage: page
    }, function(event) {
        currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
}
$pager.insertBefore($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

It works perfect. But I want use solution for settings "numPerPage" from selection. 
I added selection form array. This is still simple before script for pagination.

```
// Create selection from Array
    var arr = [
        {val : 1000, text: 'All'},
        {val : 5, text: '5'},
        {val : 10, text: '10'},
        {val : 15, text: '15'},
        {val : 20, text: '20'}
    ];

    var sel = $('<select id="selectionPerPage">').appendTo('#selection');
    $(arr).each(function() {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
    });
```

Then I added function for selection change.

```
  // Set value after selection
    $('#selectionPerPage').change(function() {
        // value and cookie
        var numPerPage = $(this).val();
    });
```

I need find solution for showing TR by "numPerPage" value If I change value in selection.

Whole script in FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/skyndas/hv979kn6/15/

Answer (score 1):

check this jsfiddle, i work for you.

```
jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vasantharaj/hv979kn6/24/
```